# Homogenous Poisson Point Process to Binomial PPP

Tags: stochastic-processes, binomial-distribution, poisson-process, point-processes

In my analysis, I am considering some nodes distributed as Homogenous Poisson Point Process (H-PPP) $\Phi$ with intensity $\lambda$. At a certain point during analysis, I need to focus on the particular area-bound $|B|$.

Can I here say that "**Our analysis hereafter focus on the area-bound around the point $O$ Hence the nodes are distributed around $O$ following binomial PPP $\Phi(|B|)$ of $\lambda |B|$ points.**"

Comment: May I know why it becomes a binomial PPP? It seems to me that it is still HPPP because you are not considering a fixed number of n points but a given bounded region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can find your answer "Stochastic Geometry
and its Applications" by Sung Nok Chiu, 3rd Edition. See Section 2.2.2 i.e. the basic properties of Binomial Point Process.

Not sure if the same applies to Homogeneous Binomial Point Process as well !